# Org-mode custom intranet links like `intra/desc`

Tags: org-mode, hyperlinks

How can I linkify the following intranet links in org-mode?

```
intra/link1-description
code/description
```

By linkify, I mean the links should be fontified and clickable in org-mode.

I don't want to add a custom link handler like `intra:` because I often copy and paste links from the intranet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those are URLs you would put in the location bar at the top of a browser window, then they represent an implied `"http://"` (or possibly `"https://"`) protocol prefix. Try making that prefix explicit in the Org link. Is it correctly clickable now?